# set default values for fields when using skip logic in qualtrics

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

If a user selects '1' for Yes, I know how to easily skip the next 5 questions in Qualtrics.

But, I don't just want to apply a logical skip and leave the fields blank. I'd like to autopopulate the skipped fields with a custom value (in my case, a -10). How can I do that?

I see information on display logic...or piping in values...but these aren't what I want. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** I am starting to suspect I will need to learn Javascript to do this...

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't something that the platform allows for natively, Though there are some decent JavaScript solutions. The specific solution will depend on what question type you are trying to populate though.

Comment: @Anthony Rivas, thanks for your commment. Is there at least some boilerplate code available somewhere? Surely I'm not the first person interested in a solution to this problem...

Comment: I have a bit that could be helpful. I'll post it as an answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to achieve this natively, instead what you want to do is use JavaScript to hide the questions when your condition is met, select the appropriate answer, and click the next button automatically. Here is a basic template for this:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{
    var skip = "${e://Field/skip}"; //Set a variable using piped text that can be used to determine whether or not to skip

    if(skip == 1){
        this.getQuestionContainer().hide(); //Hide the question
        //This section is used to set the answer value. Use the Qualtrics JS Question API to determine what you need.
        this.setChoiceValueByRecodeValue(1,true);
        //End answer setting
        $('NextButton').click(); //Click the next button
    }

});
```

Here is a very basic [preview](https://communicus.qualtrics.com/jfe/preview/SV_cJj6swl5uz4Q5Kt?Q_CHL=preview&Q_JFE=Force) using this example.

Comment: This is very helpful, thanks! Could you explain a bit about `var skip = "${e://Field/skip}";` -- how does this become `1` if the first option was selected? It looks like a path to me!

Comment: Ahh that is typical piped text, I could have just as easily used the recoded value from the question. But what I did is set up some embedded data based on the first question then used that in the second question(in a separate block). https://www.qualtrics.com/support/survey-platform/survey-module/editing-questions/piped-text/piped-text-overview/